# Why I can't catch SqlException on SaveChanges() method of Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, try-catch

I put `SaveChanges()` method inside a try/catch block, but I couldn't catch SqlExeption.

```
try
 { 
     db.SaveChanges();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 }
```

Comment: The desired behavior is explained and obvious. There is a clear problem statement. Curious as to why this was voted down...

Comment: I call BS on closing this topic.  it is OBVIOUSLY on-topic and even has example code showing what the expected behavior is.    'Wish we could vote down those who voted to close it.

Comment: should reopen and assign accepted answer @usr

Comment: The question is fine it's just not worded well. It should have said something like: `I am trying to catch SqlException to handle database errors thrown by SaveChanges(). However the exception is never caught when I use 'catch (SqlException ex)'. If instead I put 'catch(Exception ex)' then it does work. Why is this? The type of exception in the debugger shown as SqlException.`

Answer (score 17):

`SqlException` is System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException class so it's  normal that you can't catch this exception 
The  EntityFramework [`DbContext.SaveChanges Method()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges(v=vs.113).aspx) can throw the following exceptions only  as by  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges(v=vs.113).aspx)

```
DbUpdateException
DbUpdateConcurrencyException    

DbEntityValidationException 

NotSupportedException   

ObjectDisposedException 


InvalidOperationException
```

So you can  do something like  this  for example

```
try
 { 
     db.SaveChanges();
 }
 catch (DbUpdateException ex)
 {
 }
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
 {
 }
```

**More**
The exceptions mentioned  above are entity Framework Customized exceptions that only `EF` is responsible on When and How to  trigger Them take a look at [`Implementing custom exceptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception(v=vs.113).aspx#Custom)

Comment: i dont know why this question was closed , its obvious from the responses that it has an easily identifiable answer so it was a good question if simple.

this is what i ended up doing to get to the root sql error for my ui

              catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    while (ex.InnerException != null)
                        ex = ex.InnerException;
                    spanError.Text = ex.Message;
                }

Comment: Your order is wrong. You should catch `DbUpdateConcurrencyException ` first then catch `DbUpdateException`

Answer (score 5):

You cannot catch `SqlException` because it is not thrown directly, it is set as Inner Exception of the `DbUpdateException`.

Entity Framework is a abstraction to work with the databases, it does not depend on any Database technology directly.

Have a look at the Exceptions thrown by [`DbContext.SaveChanges()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)